# Cantor's Diagonal Argument - Why can't we just add any "new" real number to the list?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

my question is regarding how changing a digit from each row proves that real numbers have bigger cardinality than the usual infinity of natural numbers.

Why do we assume that there was a completion of listing the numbers in the first place that would allow us to change the numbers to create one not on the list? We are dealing with infinity after all.

And if we're allowed to create a new number by changing a digit from each row, why aren't we allowed to just add whatever that number is to the list, infinitely?

Comment: It may help to phrase the result more constructively: there is a functional $\mathscr{F}$ such that, whenever $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we have $\mathscr{F}(f)\in\mathbb{R}\setminus ran(f)$. This doesn't involve a proof by contradiction, doesn't use any intuitively-loaded language at all, and should make it clearer why moving goalposts is (as usual) unhelpful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Simply add the "new" number at the first position in the list and apply the diagonal method again. You get again a new number and so on.

Answer (score -1):

*"Why do we assume that there was a completion of listing the numbers in the first place that would allow us to change the numbers to create one not on the list?"*

The set of real numbers is either **countable** or it is **not countable**. Assume it is countable, meaning you can list every number. Do so.

If every such list you can come up with lacks some real number, then no list of real numbers contains all of the real numbers, and the set of real numbers is **not countable**.

Comment: I think Noah's comment gets at something which ought to be emphasized though: It's a completely "fake" proof by contradiction if you phrase it like that. You don't use the thing that you assume, so it is considered better practice to remove the assumption and just say: Take a function from the naturals to the set. Show that it cannot be surjective. It's very direct.

Comment: The point of that question was, once you arbitrarily assumed there could be a mapping between two infinite sets, and came to a contradiction, couldn't it mean that such a mapping is nonsensical instead of it meaning that there are two different infinite cardinalities?

Comment: @csp If you have already proven that $\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite set, and you have proven that no map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is surjective, then how else would you interpret your findings other than that there are different infinite cardinalities? Are you saying you think that no map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ exists?

Comment: @Gary In the argument there are infinite rows, and each number contains infinite digits. These plus changing a number in each row creates a "new" number not on the "list." This assumes one could somehow "freeze" the infinite rows and columns to a certain state to change the digits, instead of infinity being a process that never ends. That seems like a big assumption I'm not comfortable with.

Comment: @csp There are infinite rows because the rows are equinumerous with $\mathbb{N}$, which is an infinite set. In the same way, the set of entries in each row is equinumerous with  $\mathbb{N}$.  Are you comfortable with the existence of infinite sets? Kronecker and friends were not. It seems like you prefer constructivism. Wikipedia has a nice article on this.